# copying a sharepoint document changing the timestamp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to copy documents from SharePoint using Explorer view.

Once the copy is completed from SharePoint to my local machine folder, the file time stamp is being updated in sharepoint site with my id as last modified.

Please advice how I can retain the initial author and timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with out of the box functionality. Explorer view in sharepoint uses Webdav to connect to the document repository. You can use export functionality using stsadm, powershell and UI as well.

For UI hover your mouse to the document name field on your view ( if it is editable field) a small drop down icon appears click on this and  use send to -> download a copy.  this can be per document you have to repeat this all the documents you need

Please let us know if you need help exporting document using stsadm and powershell

Comment: I need to download multiple files and folders at once. What is the best way, using the dropdown I can just download single file.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise document(s) in your question and edited the answer. yes you cannot export multiple documents without powershell or stsadm atleast by out of the box.

Comment: Another idea if you want to use UI then you can use Central admin and navigate to backup and restore option. you can use granular export to export whole document library. this means you cannot cherry pick you documents before export.